# Passing data to another function without repeating code

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have form with input fields for some service, now I have trouble how to pass data from to function.

This form accept number and this number is multiplied to get total price, but some inputs can be 0.

I declare in globals to get value from the inputs

```
var cleaning_size;
var bathroom_number;

 $( ".needs-validation" ).on( "change", "input", function() {
    cleaning_size = $("#cleaning-size").val();
    bathroom_number = $("#bathroom-numbers").val();
})
```

And in the form i have datepicker where you chose date, but if selected sunday the price calculation is different

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        var day = date.getUTCDay();
        if (day == '6') {
            price_cleaning_size = 1.5;
            price_bathroom_number = 26;
        } else {
            price_cleaning_size = 1.2;
            price_bathroom_number = 24;
        }
    }
});
```

And then i calculate total in different function:

```
function calculate_total_value(){
  var cleaning_size_price = cleaning_size * price_cleaning_size;
  var bathromm_number_price = bathroom_number * price_bathroom_number;

  var total_price = cleaning_size_price + bathromm_number_price;
    $('#total-price strong').text(total_price).val();
}
```

Now i have issue how to get data from the datepicker if selected day is 6 to get 1.5 or 1.2 to calculate total price.

I can't find any similar example how to do this.

Also i will have timepicker what will be inside function and i will need to get value from there.

So how to pass value the right way please?

Comment: Try just calling the function after the `if/else`

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your function (`calculate_total_value()`), so it accepts two parameters - these two parameters are the values that you modify based on the selected day.

(And also check for typos like **bathromm_number_price** - they can take a lot of time to "find" later on.)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var cleaning_size;
  var bathroom_number;

  $(".needs-validation").on("change", "input", function() {
    cleaning_size = $("#cleaning-size").val();
    bathroom_number = $("#bathroom-numbers").val();
  })

  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      var day = date.getUTCDay();
      if (day == '6') {
        price_cleaning_size = 1.5;
        price_bathroom_number = 26;
      } else {
        price_cleaning_size = 1.2;
        price_bathroom_number = 24;
      }

      // call the function here, passing the values as parameters
      calculate_total_value(price_cleaning_size, price_bathroom_number)
    }
  });

  // alter your function, so it accepts two parameters (price_cleaning_size, price_bathroom_number)
  function calculate_total_value(price_cleaning_size, price_bathroom_number) {

    var cleaning_size_price = cleaning_size * price_cleaning_size;
    var bathromm_number_price = bathroom_number * price_bathroom_number;

    var total_price = cleaning_size_price + bathromm_number_price;

    $('#total-price strong').text(total_price).val();
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="needs-validation">
  <label for="cleaning-size">Cleaning size:
  <input id="cleaning-size" type="number"></label>
  <label for="bathroom-numbers">Bathroom number:
  <input id="bathroom-numbers" type="number"></label>
</div>
<h2 id="total-price"><strong>0</strong></h2>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

- `price_cleaning_size , price_bathroom_number` aren't declared anywhere. 
  It is recommended to declare the variable.(when you use `use strict`, it's must). Declare it globally.
- No where you are calling the function `calculate_total_value()`.
  It's good to call it right at bottom of onSelect call back of datepicker.

  ```
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
      var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      var day = date.getUTCDay();
      if (day == '6') {
          price_cleaning_size = 1.5;
          price_bathroom_number = 26;
      } else {
          price_cleaning_size = 1.2;
          price_bathroom_number = 24;
      }
      calculate_total_value();
  ```

  }});

When your variable scope is global, There is no point of passing as parameter to the function. Hope there is reason to declare it globally.

Hope this helps you...